# Event for movie clip loading

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there an event for when a `movieClip` loads that I can have other aspects of my flash movie react to? I would like to add an `event listener` for when movieClipOne loads that can trigger a different function in my actionscript (dim the rest of the stage).

```
movieClipOne.addEventListener(Event.NAME, dimFunction);
```

Also, if anyone can tell me the `Event.NAME` for when the application initially loads that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkLoaded)
function checkLoaded(e:Event){
if(mtERGOlink){
            // code reacting to mtERGOlink
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkLoaded)
}
}
```

This allowed me to compile and run the project as I desired. I believe that it does not make the mtERGOlink code accessable until the mtERGOlink object is available on the stage.

Thank you for the other answers - they helped lead me to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "loading". if you're using a [Loader object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) you'll need to attach events to `contentLoaderInfo` which is a [`LoaderInfo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) object.

If you're just trying to attach an event to a movie clip when it's added to the stage, you can use the [`addedToStage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event%3aaddedToStage) event which is inherited from [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html). For a complete list of supported events, just check out the docs about [`MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#eventSummary)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Loader class to load your MovieClip, then you can add event listeners to its contentLoaderInfo property:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
```

and you can also add an INIT listener too:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, handleInit);
```

each of those functions should take an Event as their sole parameter, for example:

```
function handleComplete(e:Event):void
{
//do something
}
```

Edit:
Given what you have posted as your final solution, I would say that since you are using code on the timeline, you could add event listeners to the swfs loaderInfo object, so on frame 1:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
{
// do something here
}
```

I don't think checking for the existence of some other element of the swf is the best practice although it obviously works in your case and with careful choosing / trial and error it would work for others too.